# Kubernetes installation error in flannel step

Tags: json, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, linux-kernel, app.yaml

I am installing kubernetes using kubeadm on GCP Centos VM and I am getting the following error while running flannel step.

Error:

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel created
serviceaccount/flannel created
configmap/kube-flannel-cfg created
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/a70459be0084506e4ec919aa1c114638878db11b/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml": no matches for kind "DaemonSet" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

What changes shall I made in order to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use flannel yaml from the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/2140ac876ef134e0ed5af15c65e414cf26827915/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
podsecuritypolicy.policy/psp.flannel.unprivileged created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel configured
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flannel unchanged
serviceaccount/flannel unchanged
configmap/kube-flannel-cfg configured
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-amd64 created
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm64 created
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-arm created
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-ppc64le created
daemonset.apps/kube-flannel-ds-s390x created
```

As @suren correctly mention - the issue is in the `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`

In latest yaml it looks like

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: kube-flannel-ds-amd64
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    tier: node
    app: flannel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flannel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: node
        app: flannel
...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a versioning issue with the DaemonSet and your kubernetes cluster. You are using `extensions/v1beta1`, but `DaemonSets` have been promoted to `apps/v1`.

If you already have `api-server` running, try `kubectl explain daemonset`, and it will tell you what should be the `apiVersion` for the `DaemonSets`.

If not, just download the flannel file, edit it, change the `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`, by `apiVersion: apps/v1`, and it should work.